# I cant get the mlr package to install or run

Tags: r, package, failed-installation

I ran this code 
`install.packages("mlr")`
`library(mlr)`

I get this message 
`package ‘fastmatch’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked`
`Error in install.packages : ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘C:\Users\USER\Documents\R\win-library\3.6’ for modifying`
`Try removing ‘C:\Users\USER\Documents\R\win-library\3.6/00LOCK’`

I've followed the instruction by removing folder in the last line. 
When i run the code again i get the same result.

Any answers on how to solve this?

Comment: Quit R entirely and try again. If that still fails, reboot your machine.

Comment: I've installed R 4.0.1 now and it runs